# Magento Gif upload

Tags: magento, gif, magento-2.0

I try to upload gif from admin panel of Magento2 for a feature, but it is not looping gif but a jpg at the frontend.
Looking for your advices which is also ok for Cache 
Why dosent the uploaded Gif animated ? why isnt it looping ?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Why dosent the Gif animated?why not looping ?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload images to Magento i the Wysiwyg editor. it "prepares" your images for frontend. By doing so a version of the image is stored in cache preparation.

The function that handles this is not compatible with the .gif format, and therefore i takes the first image in the row of images contained in the .gif file.

You can upload you image with a FTP client like Filezilla or through Cpanel, and overwrite the gif you already uploaded. that way the function is not run on your file, and you will keep your animated image.
There is also modules that makes the Wysiwyg editor compatible with the .gif format, for more permanent soloutions.